# Finding $a \operatorname{mod} cd$, where $c$ and $d$ are primes

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Is there a way to calculate $a \operatorname{mod} cd$, without actually calculating $cd$, where $c$ and $d$ are primes, and $cd$ has $12$ digits?

Comment: Maybe [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) is what you're looking for? It allows you to calculate $a\bmod (cd)$ if you know $a\bmod c$ and $a\bmod d$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

If we denote $a \equiv a_c \pmod c$ and $a \equiv a_d \pmod d$, we compute $c^{-1} \pmod d$ and $d^{-1} \pmod c$ using perhaps the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, then

$$a \equiv a_c d^{-1} d + a_d c^{-1} c \pmod {cd},$$

where by $c^{-1}$ and $d^{-1}$, I mean the integers calculated above by a slight abuse of notation. This is what would come from a constructive proof of the Chinese Remainder Theorem (as is highlighted in a [blog post](http://mixedmath.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/chinese-remainder-theorem-summernt/) I wrote for my students, self-plug disclaimer).